# Accepting and display special characters safely

Tags: php

I know this has been said before, and most likely a duplicate, but I'm having trouble consolidating all the information I'm finding.

I have input boxes that store information. I'd like to allow the user to type in anything they want, and display it. However, if it happens to be something like `<?php die(); ?>`, I obviously don't want it to execute.

I know there are things like `htmlspecialchars()`, however, if a user types something like `<b>` it will display `&lt;b&gt;` instead.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = '<?php echo "aaa;"?><b>sss</b>';
print "before: ". htmlspecialchars($string). "<br>";


print "after: ". cleanInput($string);

function cleanInput($input) {
    $output = strip_tags($input, '<p><a><b><div>');
    return htmlspecialchars($output);
}
```

where `<p><a><b><div>` are the allowable tags. this is good so, you can only set which tags you want to allow. This will also strip `<script>` and other tags

**Read:** http://php.net/strip_tags

Comment: I tried this, it then will execute my php code, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: As per your edit, I don't want to strip the tags either. I want to display them.

Comment: you want to display them as text or just bold if it is `<b>ss</b>`

Comment: I want to display all special characters as text. I appreciate your help, but please read the question. I am not asking to bold text inside an input.

Comment: try now. Sorry for the misunderstood. English is not my first language